# Informix 12.10 Finding the error point in the query when the statement could not be "prepare "d from the query

Tags: stored-procedures, informix

I have long query like this in the procedure

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE procedure1(var type1)
 DEFINE Result   Type2;
 LET c_query =
 "SELECT "      || 
 "RESULT "      || 
 "FROM "        ||
 "QUERY_PART1 " ||
 "join "        ||
 "QUERY_PART2 " ||
 "join "        ||
 ...
 "END_PART ";

 PREPARE c_stmt FROM c_query; --  Problematic line

 DECLARE c_cur CURSOR FOR c_stmt;
 OPEN c_cur;
 ....
 END  PROCEDURE
```

But the "PREPARE c_stmt FROM c_query;" line does not run , and the error is

```
Execute: A syntax error has occurred
```

I Try to find syntax error of Query, online, but didn't work.
Can I find the line of Error?

Can anybody Help?

Comment: Does the error relate use of "FORM" rather than "FROM"? Also, you need to include a space at the start or end of each string so that the concatenated result has spaces in the required places.
If that does not resolve the problem please provide an example of the c_stmt variable that results in a syntax error.

Comment: @SimonRiddle : No, Queries are unlikely to have this syntax errors. String concatenate  was also considered

Comment: The problematic lines are in the assignment statement before the PREPARE statement which fails.  You should normally have an ON condition after `QUERYPART2` in the statement fragment shown.  In a database where there is a table of elements and a table of isotopes, the query `select * from elements join isotopes;` generates a -201 syntax error, just as you are getting.  Seeing `END_PART` at the end of the query is puzzling too — it isn't automatically wrong, but it doesn't feel right.  Without the information represented by the `...` in the question, there's not much more that can be said.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler : ON condition was considered after join, any way T_h_a_n_k_s