# Informix 12.1 How to choose a condition, based on condition in case clause

Tags: stored-procedures, informix

| have a query in procedure like this:

```
{
 table1
column1 column2 column3 column4 
a        a       x        1      
b        b       y        4      
c        c       y        4      
d        c       y        4      
}

CREATE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1(input1 smallint)

insert into table1
select 
  column1,column2,column3,column4
From
 Table1
WHERE
 column1 not in ('a','b') 
AND
 CASE 
  WHEN input1=1 THEN  "column2 in ('a' ,'b')" --lead to syntax error and with quote, i.e. :  "column2 in (a ,b)" lead to boolean expression error  
  WHEN input1=2 THEN  "column3 in ('x' ,'y')" 
  ELSE                 "column4 not in ('1' ,'2')" 
END;
END PROCEDURE;
```

I get this error if the Condition strings in Case clause is entered with quote :

```
"Result of a boolean expression is not of boolean type"
```

If I remove quote from the Condition strings in in Case clause , I get an syntax error.

Can anybody help?

(using PREPARE statement have [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64746385/informix-12-10-finding-the-error-point-in-the-query-when-the-statement-could-not?noredirect=1#comment114527114_64746385))

Comment: Please clarify what on earth you mean by "Condition_part2{1,2,3}".  Maybe you can show an example of what those values are — part of creating an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses).  If you're trying to use characters strings to express part of the query, you should be using the PREPARE statement and its relatives in the stored procedure.  See [Example of PREPARE in a stored procedure](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1881.htm)

Comment: You've edited, but it isn't an MCVE.  It isn't inside a CREATE PROCEDURE statement, for starters.  There's no illustration of what `input`, `Condition_psrt1`, `Condition_part21`, `Condition_part22`, `Condition_part23` are.  However, unless `input1` is a numeric column in `Table1` and the others are all the names of boolean columns in `Table1`, you have major problems (syntax errors).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler :I corrected again

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  :Working with prepare is not possible because the query is too large to make an error and in this way the line number is not specified. Anyway, t_h_a_n_k you for your a_t_t_e_n_t_i_o_n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do might require:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
    SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4
      FROM Table1
     WHERE column1 NOT IN ('a', 'b') 
       AND ((input1  = 1 AND column2 IN ('a', 'b')) OR
            (input1  = 2 AND column3 IN ('x', 'y')) OR
            (input1 != 1 AND input1 != 2 AND column4 NOT IN ('1', '2'))
           )
```

Note that I've changed the target table for the INSERT to `Table2`; there isn't a good reason to insert rows into the table you're selecting the data from — the data is already there and duplicate rows only add confusion.  However, if you insist that the target table should be the same as the source table and there is no primary key to stop you abusing it, then you can use `INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT … FROM Table1 …`, somewhat to my surprise (Informix 12.10.FC6 tested).

You could rewrite that as:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
    SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4
      FROM Table1
     WHERE column1 NOT IN ('a', 'b') 
       AND ((input1     IN (1)    AND column2     IN ('a', 'b')) OR
            (input1     IN (2)    AND column3     IN ('x', 'y')) OR
            (input1 NOT IN (1, 2) AND column4 NOT IN ('1', '2'))
           )
```

That emphasizes the similarities and differences in the major components of the OR'd terms.

Assembling an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) from this produces:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table2;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedure1;

CREATE TEMP TABLE Table1
(
    column1 CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    column2 CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    column3 CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    column4 CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES('a', 'a', 'x', '1');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES('b', 'b', 'y', '4');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES('c', 'c', 'y', '4');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES('d', 'c', 'y', '4');

CREATE TEMP TABLE Table2
(
    column1 CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    column2 CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    column3 CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    column4 CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

CREATE PROCEDURE procedure1(input1 SMALLINT)

    INSERT INTO Table2
        SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4
          FROM Table1
         WHERE column1 NOT IN ('a', 'b') 
           AND ((input1  = 1 AND column2 IN ('a', 'b')) OR
                (input1  = 2 AND column3 IN ('x', 'y')) OR
                (input1 != 1 AND input1 != 2 AND column4 NOT IN ('1', '2'))
               );

    INSERT INTO Table2
        SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4
          FROM Table1
         WHERE column1 NOT IN ('a', 'b') 
           AND ((input1     IN (1)    AND column2     IN ('a', 'b')) OR
                (input1     IN (2)    AND column3     IN ('x', 'y')) OR
                (input1 NOT IN (1, 2) AND column4 NOT IN ('1', '2'))
               );

END PROCEDURE;

EXECUTE PROCEDURE procedure1(1);
SELECT * FROM Table2;
DELETE FROM Table2;

EXECUTE PROCEDURE procedure1(2);
SELECT * FROM Table2;
DELETE FROM Table2;

EXECUTE PROCEDURE procedure1(3);
SELECT * FROM Table2;
```

Using my [SQLCMD](https://www.iiug.org/en/iiug-software-repository/#ESQL) program (unrelated to, and older than, Microsoft's johnny-come-lately program of the same name), I get:

```
+ DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table1;
+ DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table2;
+ DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedure1;
+ CREATE TEMP TABLE Table1
(
    column1 CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    column2 CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    column3 CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    column4 CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);
+ INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES('a', 'a', 'x', '1');
+ INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES('b', 'b', 'y', '4');
+ INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES('c', 'c', 'y', '4');
+ INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES('d', 'c', 'y', '4');
+ CREATE TEMP TABLE Table2
(
    column1 CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    column2 CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    column3 CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    column4 CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);
+ CREATE PROCEDURE procedure1(input1 SMALLINT)

    INSERT INTO Table2
        SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4
          FROM Table1
         WHERE column1 NOT IN ('a','b') 
           AND ((input1  = 1 AND column2 IN ('a' ,'b')) OR
                (input1  = 2 AND column3 IN ('x' ,'y')) OR
                (input1 != 1 AND input1 != 2 AND column4 NOT IN ('1' ,'2'))
               );

    INSERT INTO Table2
        SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4
          FROM Table1
         WHERE column1 NOT IN ('a','b') 
           AND ((input1     IN (1)    AND column2     IN ('a' ,'b')) OR
                (input1     IN (2)    AND column3     IN ('x' ,'y')) OR
                (input1 NOT IN (1, 2) AND column4 NOT IN ('1' ,'2'))
               );

END PROCEDURE;
+ EXECUTE PROCEDURE procedure1(1);
+ SELECT * FROM Table2;
+ DELETE FROM Table2;
+ EXECUTE PROCEDURE procedure1(2);
+ SELECT * FROM Table2;
c|c|y|4
d|c|y|4
c|c|y|4
d|c|y|4
+ DELETE FROM Table2;
+ EXECUTE PROCEDURE procedure1(3);
+ SELECT * FROM Table2;
c|c|y|4
d|c|y|4
c|c|y|4
d|c|y|4
```

Since there are two INSERT statements, it is expected that Table2 will contain two copies of each row inserted.  Of course, the table should have a primary key to prevent such abuses of relational theory.

You should also consider whether you'd be better off writing the 3 operations separately without mentioning `input1` in the queries:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure2(input1 SMALLINT)

    IF input1 = 1 THEN
        INSERT INTO Table2
            SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4
              FROM Table1
             WHERE column1 NOT IN ('a', 'b') 
               AND column2     IN ('a', 'b');
    ELIF input1 = 2 THEN
        INSERT INTO Table2
            SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4
              FROM Table1
             WHERE column1 NOT IN ('a', 'b') 
               AND column3     IN ('x', 'y');
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO Table2
            SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4
              FROM Table1
             WHERE column1 NOT IN ('a', 'b') 
               AND column4 NOT IN ('1', '2');
    END IF;

END PROCEDURE;
```

You might also consider using views or even the CTE (common table expression) feature if your query is massively big.